# More sophisticated way to split column from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, optimization

I have an array in the following format:

```
let initialDataset=

[
    [3.6216,8.6661,-2.8073,-0.44699,1  ],
    [4.5459,8.1674,-2.4586,-1.4621,0  ],
    [3.866,-2.6383,1.9242,0.10645,1  ],
    [3.4566,9.5228,-4.0112,-3.5944,0  ],
    [0.32924,-4.4552,4.5718,-0.9888,0  ],

//and so on...
```

**Goal:** Seperate last column/element from each array inside 'initialDataset' variable and put them into a distinct array. They have to be in the same index too. Such as:

```
let initialDataset=

    [
        [3.6216,8.6661,-2.8073,-0.44699],
        [4.5459,8.1674,-2.4586,-1.4621],
        [3.866,-2.6383,1.9242,0.10645],
        [3.4566,9.5228,-4.0112,-3.5944],
        [0.32924,-4.4552,4.5718,-0.9888],

let division=[1,0,1,0,0];
```

To accomplish this, i used following piece of code:

```
let division=[];
for(i=0;i<initialDataset.length;i++){
    division[i]=initialDataset[i].pop();
}
```

It gets the work done but i didn't quite like it. Looking for a better way to achieve it. Any suggestions in terms of optimization and code quality wise ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Notice, that `pop` mutates the original array, the last "column" is removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could map the popped value.

```js
var data = [[3.6216, 8.6661, -2.8073, -0.44699, 1], [4.5459, 8.1674, -2.4586, -1.4621, 0], [3.866, -2.6383, 1.9242, 0.10645, 1], [3.4566, 9.5228, -4.0112, -3.5944, 0], [0.32924, -4.4552, 4.5718, -0.9888, 0]],
    division = data.map(a => a.pop());

console.log(division);
```

Answer (score 2):

Functional answer using a handy, reusable `last` function. This method does not mutate the input array.

```js
const data = [[3.6216,8.6661,-2.8073,-0.44699,1],[4.5459,8.1674,-2.4586,-1.4621,0],[3.866,-2.6383,1.9242,0.10645,1],[3.4566,9.5228,-4.0112,-3.5944,0],[0.32924,-4.4552,4.5718,-0.9888,0]]

const last = array => {
  const { length } = array
  return length > 0 ? array[length - 1] : undefined
}

const division = data.map(last)

console.log(division)
```